# Why does a MFC application behaves mysteriously in encrypted hard drive environment

Tags: mfc

I'm working on a bug where I have an MFC application that does weird things when installed in when Sophos Safeguard hard drive encryption is installed. I'm sorry to be so vague here, but I'm writing this away from the office so this is all from my (poor) memory.

Three things I've noticed:

1. AfxGetResourceHandle() doesn't return a consistent resource handle. There is a single case where we try to load a string resource, and for some reason, the resource handle that we get from this method is different to all the other stings.
2. Can't construct a CDocumentTemplate. There is a trace error which I cant seem to recall. Will edit and post when I'm in tomorrow.
3. This behaviour appears to manifest in a Visual Studio 2005 version of the project, but not a Visual Studio 2008 version. Unfortunately moving to the 2008 version is not an option.

The bug is not always reproducable if I step through with a debugger. Also, bringing up debug message boxes changes the behaviuor, which leads me to think that either there is some kind of race condition going on with the way MFC events are being handled, but I'm not sure how I'll ever know for sure, or even what I can do about it if I did.

I think there's some underlying reason that the app is behaving weirdly, but what I've posted are more symptoms. Can anyone think of what I should check for?

I've run Windows update on the test environment to ensure everything was up to date, and I've examined the process in procmon to see if the disk encryption stuff was getting in the way and conflicting with files - it didn't appear to be, but it does appear to be involved in some way as our app accesses Sophos related paths in the temp directory.

Comment: maybe the slow down of disk access caused by the encryption, is changing the timing of some buggy threaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the antivirus software was injecting itself in a way where the antivirus' software's resource handles were overridng the app's resource handles. Yuck!

Answer (score 0):

If your code is multithreaded (which I assume it is, since you mentioned the possibility of a race condition), then the likelihood is that the decryption delays are exposing concurrency flaws. You might want to try running the application off of a network share or similar slow access device to see if it manifests similar problems.